# Compare multiple columns from 1 database to multiple columns in a different database in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In 1 database I have 5 DATE fields and in the other database I have 10 DATE fields.
Alot of those fields are 1900-01-01 or empty.

What I want to do is check if one or more columns from the first database match with one of the dates in the second database.

In the code Below I check if DB1_date1 value matches with the DB2_date1 value.

```
     ,case
            when (len([DB1_date1]) = 0 and len([DB2_date1]) = 0) then 1
            when len([DB1_date1]) = 0 and [DB2_date1]= '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' then 1
            when (right([DB1_date1], 4) = '0000' or right([DB2_date1] , 2) = '00' or right([DB2_date1] , 4) = '0000' or right([DB1_date1], 2) = '00') then 5
            when cast([DB1_date1] as date) = cast([DB2_date1] as date) and (len([DB1_date1]) > 0 and len([DB2_date1]) > 0) then 0
            when len([DB1_date1]) = 0 and cast([DB1_date1] as date) <> cast([DB2_date1] as date) then 2
            when [DB2_date1] = '' and cast([DB1_date1] as date) <> cast([DB2_date1]as date) then 3
            when len([DB1_date1]) > 0 and cast([DB1_date1] as date) <> cast([DB2_date1] as date) then 4
else 5
            end as DateChk
```

The problem is for example DB2_date4 can exist in DB1_date1. So if I continue writing my script with this logic I have to create a million when cases.

Does someone have any idea how I can begin writing a better script? performance doesnt matter.

Im using SQL server 16

EDIT:

```
DECLARE @Table_1 TABLE(ID INT, T1_Date_1 DATE, T1_Date_2 DATE, T1_Date_3 DATE)
 
INSERT INTO @Table_1
VALUES 
(1,'1900-01-01', '1900-01-01', '1900-01-01')  ,
(2,'1900-01-01', '1974-01-01', '1900-01-01')  ,
(3,'1900-01-01', '1900-01-01', '2021-01-01')  ,
(4,'1900-01-01', '2021-01-01', '1900-01-01')  

SELECT * FROM @Table_1

DECLARE @Table_2 TABLE(ID INT, T2_Date_1 DATE, T2_Date_2 DATE, T2_Date_3 DATE, T2_Date_4 DATE);
 
INSERT INTO @Table_2
VALUES 
(1,'1900-01-01', '1900-01-01', '1900-01-01', '1900-01-01')  ,
(2,'1900-01-01', '1974-01-01', '1900-01-01', '1900-01-01')  ,
(3,'2021-01-01', '1900-01-01', '1900-01-01', '1900-01-01')  ,
(4,'1900-01-01', '2014-01-01', '1900-01-01', '1900-01-01')  

SELECT * FROM @Table_2
```

1900-01-01 means no date.

The desired result is:

ID 1 = nothing.(nothing because there is no date in both tables)

ID 2 = nothing.(there is 1 date in both tables and they match)

ID 3 = nothing.(there is 1 date in both tables and they match)

ID 4 = Check.(there is a date in both tables and they do not match)

Comment: When you say "database" do you actually mean "table"? Your question looks like you're asking about a cross-database implementation.

Comment: The tables are in different databases but yes I want to compare the columns from 2 tables.

Comment: Include a proper working query in your question with sample data and desired results, when asking a SQL question a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is useful.

Comment: `len([DB1_date1])`??? The lengths of actual `date` columns are always the same because they're a binary type. Are you storing date-like strings in columns with n/char or n/varchar data types?

Comment: The database is from a CSV file so yes everything is a String. I edited some code with example data and added the desired result.

Comment: @Jelmer Your tables have columns defined as DATE; It is irrelevant how those get populated. Your use of all those string functions makes no logical sense and is highly risky due to the implicit datatype conversions you use. And DATES have no time portion at all - so attempting to compare those parts is pointless. You only need to check for values that are NULL or '19000101' for special logic. And notice that your code fragment does not match your DDL - adding confusion.

Comment: @Smor I think I did not explain myself correctly. I work as a data scientist. I have to compare 2 big datasets with eachother and check if there are any errors. everything I get is in string format. I cant cast them beforehand as a DATE because some of the fields are just not formatted correctly or even contain letters, but that is irrelevant.
The thing I need to do is compare 5 columns from 1 table to 10 columns from another table and check if every date matches.